# How to select node and parent nodes with AngleSharp?

Tags: c#, css-selectors, anglesharp

With HtmlAgilityPack, I do this

```
var elements= HAPdoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(XPathSelector).AncestorsAndSelf()
```

Any idea on how can I do this with AngleSharp and CSS selector?

```
var elements = AngleSharpDoc.QuerySelectorAll("Some CSS selector ?");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you use `SelectSingleNode` but `QuerySelectorAll`. The former selects 1 (one!) node, the latter n (many!) nodes. Therefore, just use `QuerySelector`. Second, for a single node AngleSharp gives you quite a few extensions in the `AngleSharp.Extensions` namespace.

You'll find

```
var elements = document.QuerySelector("...").Ancestors();
```

If you want both (the child and its parents) I'll recommend something like

```
var child = document.QuerySelector("...");
var elements = child.Ancestors().ToList();
elements.Insert(child, 0);
```

The list of ancestors is an enumerable over `INode`. If you are only interested in, e.g., `IElement` instances you can also use

```
var elements = document.QuerySelector("...").Ancestors<IElement>();
```